# sudo apt-get upgrade (E : unmet dependencies error)

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, package-management

I'm completely new to linux. If someone could make out from the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk3vN.png) whats wrong it would be really helpful. Also I'm getting that red icon on the top panel.

I tried running these code :-

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.old
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

The above code made that red icon go away after I rebooted but when I used the sudo apt-get upgrade after using sudo apt-get update command it popped up back again.

`sudo apt-get -f install` gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CZHt.png) output error

Also I have referred to this thread (How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?) but to no avail.

After running the `sudo dpkg -- configure -a` it gives me following error.

```
instincts@Instincts:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for instincts: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ppa-purge:
ppa-purge depends on aptitude.

dpkg: error processing package ppa-purge (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of aptitude:i386:
aptitude:i386 depends on libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 0.8.16~exp12ubuntu6).
aptitude:i386 depends on libboost-iostreams1.46.1 (>= 1.46.1-1).
aptitude:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
aptitude:i386 depends on libcwidget3.
aptitude:i386 depends on libept1.4.12.
aptitude:i386 depends on libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1).
aptitude:i386 depends on libncursesw5 (>= 5.6+20070908).
aptitude:i386 depends on libsigc++-2.0-0c2a (>= 2.0.2).
aptitude:i386 depends on libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.6.5).
aptitude:i386 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.6).
aptitude:i386 depends on libtinfo5.
aptitude:i386 depends on libxapian22.

dpkg: error processing package aptitude:i386 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
ppa-purge
aptitude:i386
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You probably will find the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa).

Answer (score 1):

You can try fixing the broken dependencies using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Then run this again:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

You can find in details how to fix the dependency error in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) thread.

Comment: I have updated my question. Plz have a look.

Comment: Sometimes it's easier just to reinstall ubuntu. I had unmet dependency errors a while back and the only way to fix it was to reinstall ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

and if you are running latest Ubuntu

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and then

```
apt-get -f install
```

Comment: "sudo apt-get update" works fine.  "sudo apt-get upgrade" and "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" share the same error which i have posted in the question above (1st image link). Also error for "sudo apt-get -f install" is posted. Thanx for trying to answer though.

Comment: Try to go to repository manager (ubuntu software) and check if main and contrib repositories are checked.

Comment: U mean [this](https://ibb.co/mHehNF) right ?? I had those checked.

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled ubuntu and obviously it solved the error.